MediaWiki: Recommendation for directory of deleted files
Where and why should MediaWiki move deleted files?
screenshot
I'm about to install release 1.39.7 with the intention of providing a wiki that will be used for at least ten years.
Help me to prevent any potential issues in the long term, please.

I have no experience with mediawiki but in general you only change defaults when your usage patterns, benchmarking,  testing and other requirements suggest that you need to. I'd start with a different question: "Do you want  to keep deleted files (indefinitely) , should you want that and are you allowed to?"  Or is better to run a daily maintenance job that cleans up deleted files when Mediawiki does not allow you to set a retention policy that automatically permanently deletes  those files?

Thank you for contributing. Once I'm permitted to vote up, I'll give you +1.

This is the directory, to which MediaWiki will move the files, the wiki pages for which (File:) are deleted in the wiki.
You may want to set it to its default value "{$wgUploadDirectory}/deleted".
You can change this setting later, by editing LocalSettings.php; but unless you are short of storage room, or you want to make sure that these files canot be served by your web server, you won't need it.
See $wgDeletedDirectory.
